# Populate Room Database with Arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, arraylist, android-room

I would like to build a Deckbuilder that allows you to save created decks locally on the device.

The Decklist are stored in Arraylists, called `TransferDeck`. Which I would like to store in room database. **My issue is, that I do not know how to populate my database correctly, with the data comming out of the Arraylist.**

I am used to working with Arraylist and below you see my try for storing the data:

**So this is what I tried but what sadly does not work:**

```
private void populateDB(final List<TransferDeck> mTransferDeck) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<SaveDeck> mSaveDeck = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i = 0; i<mTransferDeck.size(); i++){
                        mSaveDeck.add(new SaveDeck(i, "FirstSavedDeck", mTransferDeck.get(i).getCardImage() ,mTransferDeck.get(i).getTypeImage(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getCost(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getName(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getNumber()));
                    }
                    mSavedDecksDB.deckBuilderDao().insertCards(mSaveDeck);

                }
            }).start();
}
```

***Below you can find the rest of my code, but the above one should be enough to make clear what I want to do...***

1. I created the class SaveDeck which should be able to *Save a Deck with a given Deckname*:
   :-

   @Entity
   public class SaveDeck implements Serializable {
       @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
       private int _id;

   ```
   public SaveDeck(int _id, String deckName, int cardImage, int typeImage, Integer cardCost, String cardName, Integer cardNumber) {
       this._id = _id;
       DeckName = deckName;
       CardImage = cardImage;
       TypeImage = typeImage;
       CardCost = cardCost;
       CardName = cardName;
       CardNumber = cardNumber;
   }

   @ColumnInfo(name = "DeckName")
   private String DeckName;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "CardImage")
   private int CardImage;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "TypeImage")
   private int TypeImage;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "CardCost")
   private Integer CardCost;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "CardName")
   private String CardName;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "CardNumber")
   private Integer CardNumber;
   ```

   }
2. I created the Dao Class as follows:
   :-

   @Dao
   public interface DeckBuilderDao {

   ```
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   public long[] insertCards(SaveDeck... saveDecks);

   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   public long insertCard(SaveDeck saveDecks);

   @Update
   public int updateCardBaseEntries(SaveDeck... saveDecks);

   @Update
   public int updateCardBaseEntry(SaveDeck saveDecks);

   @Delete
   public int deleteCardBaseEntried(SaveDeck... saveDecks);

   @Delete
   public int deleteCardBaseEntry(SaveDeck saveDecks);

   @Query("SELECT * FROM SaveDeck")
   public SaveDeck[] getAllDecks();

   //probably I do not need the getAllDecks Query. Right now I only need the following one:
   @Query("SELECT * FROM SaveDeck WHERE DeckName = :NameOfDeck ORDER  BY DeckName, CardName")
   public SaveDeck getOneDeck(String NameOfDeck);
   ```

   }
3. Furthermore created the DataBase Class:

   ```
   @Database(entities = {SaveDeck.class}, version = 1)
   public abstract class SaveDecksDataBase extends RoomDatabase {
       public abstract DeckBuilderDao deckBuilderDao();
   }
   ```
4. The last class is a fragment, where I try to populate my database, and in the `populateDB()` class is the issue

   public class review_fragment extends Fragment {

   ```
   private List<TransferDeck> mTransferDeck = DataHolder.getInstance().savedDecklistTransfer;
   SaveDecksDataBase mSavedDecksDB;
   Cursor mCursor;

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.review_fragment, container, false);

       /*Introduce Cards Recycler*/

       RecyclerView rvCards = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_review_cardlist);
       rvCards.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 5));
       review_RViewAdapter_Cards adapterCards = new review_RViewAdapter_Cards(getContext(), mTransferDeck);
       rvCards.setAdapter(adapterCards);



       /*Init Room database*/
       mSavedDecksDB = Room.databaseBuilder(getActivity(),SaveDecksDataBase.class,"SavedDecksDB.db").build();
       populateDB(mTransferDeck);

       return view;
   }

   private void populateDB(final List<TransferDeck> mTransferDeck) {
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               List<SaveDeck> mSaveDeck = new ArrayList<>();
               for(int i = 0; i<mTransferDeck.size(); i++){
                   mSaveDeck.add(new SaveDeck(i, "FirstSavedDeck", mTransferDeck.get(i).getCardImage() ,mTransferDeck.get(i).getTypeImage(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getCost(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getName(), mTransferDeck.get(i).getNumber()));
               }
               mSavedDecksDB.deckBuilderDao().insertCards(mSaveDeck);

           }
       }).start();
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

I like to mention that this should be a comment rather than an answer.

First, either use [`AysncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or use more robust `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. If you prefer the second one then it's best if you create a helper class [(example)](https://gist.github.com/RajarshiMandal/599fdbfd1d95754407a02f48e626b65f). Example:

```
private void populateDB(final List<TransferDeck> mTransferDeck) {
    AppExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {

        for(int i = 0; i<mTransferDeck.size(); i++){
            mSavedDecksDB.deckBuilderDao().insertCards(new SaveDeck(...);
        }

    });
}
```

(1) Create a blank constructor.

(4) Room Database should not be initialized there and it's best if it's singleton. So the your database class (3) can be like:

```
public abstract class SaveDecksDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

   private static SaveDecksDataBase sINSTANCE;
   private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

   public static SaveDecksDataBase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (sINSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (sINSTANCE == null) {
                    sINSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            SaveDecksDataBase.class, "SavedDecksDB.db")
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return sINSTANCE;
    }

    public abstract DeckBuilderDao deckBuilderDao();
}
```

Lastly, to get `SaveDeck` object you also has to use `Executors` or `AsyncTask` to do the work in background, and then populate the `RecyclerView`.

1. [Android Room Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)
2. [Practice set](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0)

Comment: Thanks bro, I had an important exam. I will check it out later. What is the advantage of Executors vs AsyncTask, as in whats the main difference and what is easier for a beginner? :)